# Why csrf token must be put in body for POST requests and not in headers in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, csrf

I would like to know the reason why we must put the csrf token in the **body** for POST requests (key `csrfmiddlewaretoken`) and in the **headers** for the others (key `X-CSRFToken`)?

Comment: It can also be put in the header for POST requests, for example through AJAX.

Comment: Oh god, it seems to be true, I don't know why it was not working well when I tried with postman.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the header in case of a POST request as well. Indeed, this is often done for POST requests with AJAX (and other requests with side-effects). This is demonstrated in the [*Setting the token on the AJAX request* section of the documentation <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request):

> Finally, you’ll need to set the header on your AJAX request. Using the
> `fetch()` API:
>
> ```
> const request = new Request(
>     /* URL */,
>     {
>         method: 'POST',
>         headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
>         mode: 'same-origin' // Do not send CSRF token to another domain.
>     }
> );
> fetch(request).then(function(response) {
>     // ...
> });
> ```